# Rails belongs_to relationship with multiple possibilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, relationship, belongs-to

I'm trying to make a relationship where a model, `Information`, belongs_to either a `User` or a `Client`.

I thought about putting in my `Information.rb`

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :client
```

and in `User.rb` and `Client.rb`

has_one :information

But that makes it so that an information could `belong_to` both a `User` and a `Client`.

Is there a way to make it so that it can only belong to either or without just leaving one of the fields blank?

P.S. If it is needed I'm using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.1, and Devise for my account authentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an unusual association but it's a good fit for [Polymorphic Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). In this case, you would declare a name for this association

```
class Information < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :informational, polymorphic: true #or something like it

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many informations, as :informational

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many informations, as :informational
```

And you would also need to add two columns to `Information` 
`informational_id, :integer` and `informational_type, :string`

and `Client` and `User` need a integer called `informational_id` that is indexed.

Comment: Yes. Should be fine to use to use `has_one` instead of many. The important part is the type and id so it can determine association.